# SQL Date clause for Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am developing a report using SQL and SSRS that gives a day by day breakdown of stats from the 1st of the month to the previous day.

However, on the 1st of the month the report comes up blank when I need it to show the previous months information (e.g. on the 1st of February I want a report that gives me a day by day breakdown of January from the 1st to 31st.

I tried the following case statement in the SQL where clause to see if it would fix the issue but it doesn't seem to work:

```
(dIntervalStart BETWEEN dbo.DateAndTime(CASE WHEN DAY(GEtDate()) = 1 THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE() - 1), 0) ELSE DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) END, '00:00:00')
```

Is there something else that might work?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @StartOfMOnth bit
declare @startDate date
declare @endDate date

select @StartOfMOnth =
case  when datepart(dd, getdate()) <> 1 then 0
else  1
end


IF (@StartOfMOnth = 0) --If not start of month
BEGIN
SELECT @startDate =  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) --First day of current month
SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE())--Previous day
END

ELSE --If start of month

BEGIN
SELECT @startDate =  DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) --First day of last month
SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))--Last day of last month
END

--Once you have start and end dates, do what needs to be done in the dataset
```